# How to trigger a login popup using an intercepting servlet-filter

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlet-filters

On a java webapp, I wish to protect access to any resources that have this pattern: http://www.example.com/private/*

I wish to secure that url pattern with a filter like this:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/private/*", filterName = "SecurityFilter")
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {
   ...
}
```

When the user tries to access a *protected* URL, and is logged in, then the filter is a pass-thru; However, if the user isn't logged in or the session has expired, then the filter should result in a login popup in the browser, **without changing (by forwarding/redirecting/reloading) the original parent html5 page on which the user was on, originally**.

The part I'm having difficulty with, is how to **trigger** that popup using the filter's response? I was toying with the idea of using SSE (server-sent events) or websockets to have the html5 page listen for a *"login required"* kind of event, but I feel that is too extreme for my needs, and that a simpler approach is probably eluding me.

*P.S. I do not necessarily need details, just the high-level idea/approach would be appreciated.*

Comment: This is a pretty broad question in terms of *how can I do this*.  The filter will have to have some way of signaling to the frontend that it should perform the authentication.  And if it can happen on any page, then every page will have to have the ability to show the popup and handle for the authentication.  This means either the all frontend pages will have to have the ability to handle for this, or the backend will have to conditionally include in the response source the ability to show the popup and handle for it's logic.

Comment: In simply in the request-reponse paradism, from the servlet filter you must to reponse something that the browser obey, you could send redirect response. but the redirect is in the same window, so it wont open a popup.